# Does @jit run a python code on the gpu if we do not explicitly mention a target?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, anaconda, numba

I have a python code I am trying to accelerate using Cuda. I have used the @jit function. How do I know if the code is actually being run on the gpu? Is there any way to check/verify that?

Answer (score 2):

You should use numba.cuda.jit in order to run your jitted function on GPU. Moreover, this function should be written in the manner of CUDA kernel (http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.30.1/cuda/kernels.html). When the function runs some GPU monitor (for example nvidia-smi for Linux) can be used to see the GPU load and to check that it is involved in calculation.